# Concerns about network traffic

Tags: sql-server

I was reading about 'data relation' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810294.aspx) and I was confused about how it works. For example, does sql server duplicates data when returning the results above or does it returns in any intelligent way to avoid redundance?

```
create table #category(Id int, Name varchar(100))
create table #product(Id int, Name varchar(100), CategoryId int)

insert into #category values (1, 'category 1')

insert into #product values (1, 'Product 1', 1)
insert into #product values (2, 'Product 2', 1)
insert into #product values (3, 'Product 3', 1)
insert into #product values (4, 'Product 4', 1)
insert into #product values (5, 'Product 5', 1)

select * from #product left join #category on #product.categoryid = #category.id
```

[image]

Comment: This is database 101. You are joining in your `category` table to your `product` table. You have the same `categoryid` for each product so your `category.name` WILL be the same for each one. How else would you expect it? That's not "Duplicate data". That is the category name for that record's product.

Comment: @JNevill I understood OP's question to be more in regards to SQL's efficiency when returning duplicate data, using that simply as an example. Though personally, I'm not too confident in either direction - the question could certainly benefit from some clarification.

Comment: @Santi Please, edit it. My english is not very good to be more precise.

Comment: If you'd like me to edit it, you'll first need to give me a bit more information - I'm truthfully not exactly sure what you're asking myself.

Answer (score 1):

It will duplicate the data.

You can use over-the-wire tools to see exactly what is being transferred between the server and the client when doing performance analysis such as this.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

All the results are sent from the server to the client in a row/column format.  It's been standardized that way in the SQL Server API for years and years, and cannot be changed.  It is designed to allow result sets to be traversed on the client side, one row at a time, without the server having to send all the data to the client at once.

Concerns about modifying how SQL Server works internally are probably a waste of your time.  If there's a real issue with "duplication" as you've mentioned (a misnomer), it might be addressed at the network level.